# importlib.import_module ignoring re-exports made in __init__.py

Tags: python, django, python-module, python-importlib

(Originally asked on [r/learnpython](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/g8psj4/ask_anything_monday_weekly_thread/fp923c0?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x), but figured I'd ask here too.)

Since this problem came up while dealing with django, I'll explain in that context.

So I have a django project folder, and some internal django apps living in that project folder, like this:

```
project_module
├ apps
│ ├ app_module1
│ │ ├ models.py
│ │ └ ...
│ ├ app_module2
│ └ ...
├ settings.py
└ ...
```

now the app_modules are available as `project_module.apps.app_module1` and so on, but since there won't be anything colliding with the app names in `project_module`, I'd like to drop the `.apps` part so I can just refer to them as `project_module.app_module1` and such, consistently.

So, I create `__init__.py` everywhere, and put this into `project_module/__init__.py`:

```
from .apps import app_module1
```

And this sort of works, since I can `import project_module.app_module1` and it seems to work.

BUT, Django internally uses `importlib.import_module` here and there, and in those cases I encounter `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project_module.app_module1'`. In those cases I can use the `.apps` again, but this sort of breaks consistency.

A bit of experiment later, I'm convinced `import_module` ignores re-exports from `__init__.py`; But why does this happen, and is there a way I can play around this in this case?

Comment: "And this sort of works, since I can `import project_module.app_module1` and it seems to work." - are you sure? That shouldn't actually work. You would need to do `from project_module import app_module1`.

Comment: If you want to drop the `.apps` part, why not just *actually eliminate* the `apps` subpackage and move the contents into `project_module`?

Comment: @user2357112 Hmm, you're right, I can't `import project_module.app_module1`. I must have confused it with something else, my bad. As for removing `apps` subpackage, I certainly could do that, but I'd also like to keep apps in their own directory because... it feels more organized that way? I dunno.

Comment: So I'm guessing that importing (and re-exporting) a module makes it an attribute of current module or something like that, but not its actual submodule. That'd mean I can't fiddle with module structure via imports in `__init__.py`; But then, is there a way to fiddle with it at all?

Answer (score 0):

> So, I create **init**.py everywhere, and put this into project_module/**init**.py

Consider adding project_module/apps to PYTHONPATH or `sys.path` if you're really determined to remove `app` from imports. That's also a hack in this use-case, but more predictable.