# Is python's module hierachy tied to directory structure?

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

Consider this a more refined version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61557895/importlib-import-module-ignoring-re-exports-made-in-init-py/61558060#61558060).

It seems python's module structure is tied to actual directory containing the files. While it is possible to re-export another module using `__init__.py`, this does not alter the actual module hierachy as log as the import facility is concerned.

For instance:

```
some_dir
├ main.py
└ mod_a
  ├ __init__.py
  └ mod_b
    └ mod_c.py
```

`mod_a/__init__.py`:

```
from .mod_b import mod_c
```

`mod_a/mod_b/mod_c.py`:

```
def foo():
    print("Foo!")
```

In this case, we can do this in `main.py`:

```
from mod_a import mod_c

mod_c.foo()
```

but not this:

```
import mod_a.mod_c

mod_c.foo()
```

which fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mod_a.mod_c
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mod_a.mod_c'
```

So **init**.py can't exactly alter module hierachy; And this is the closest thing to 'altering module hierachy' in python I know of.

So, is there a way to the alter the module hierachy? As in:

- a way to make `import mod_a.mod_c` a valid import statement?
- a way to mount some python module in arbitrary path to some import-path, in general?

Comment: Have you seen https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html ?

Comment: import mod_a does not import its submodules, it only automatically imports mod_a.__init__

Comment: @MatsLindh I have, but I skimmed over looking for a more straight forward answer. Nevertheless, it was a step in the right direction, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by modifying `__path__`, with [`pkgutil.extend_path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.extend_path) or by other means.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#module-path):

> A package’s `__path__` attribute is used during imports of its subpackages. Within the import machinery, it functions much the same as `sys.path`, i.e. providing a list of locations to search for modules during import.

`__path__` may be modified in the module's `__init__.py` to change where import system searches for submodules.

In given case, using `pkgutil.extend_path`:

```py
# mod_a/__init__.py
from pkgutil import extend_path

__path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__ + '.mod_b')
```

or by modifying `__path__` manually:

```py
# mod_a/__init__.py
__path__.append("(...)/some_dir/mod_a/mod_b")
```

where the actual path to the `mod_b` is preferably computed from `__file__`.

[These](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2699287/4516872) SO question and answers cover more about using `__path__`.